# Creating a dynamic datatable vue js

Tags: vue.js, svg, datatable, bootstrap-vue

I have a requirement to build a data table/svg  graph which would look like the image below so the idea is we'll use axios to get data like what are the departments and projects and how many employees from particular department is working on particular project (basically the count). i could build a table just for projects or just for departments with b-tables

but i need them to be both column and horizonal headers 
[image]

*sorry for the vague image

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you want to dynamically create your table based on `departments`, `projects` and `employees` so you can quickly see how many in each `department` is working on a given `project`.

I've tried doing that dynamically (with mock data since i don't know how your data is structured)
https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/qBWywdM?editors=1010

Comment: And if you want the department column to be a "row header" see this minor adjustment https://codepen.io/tmorehouse/pen/pozZmwQ?editors=1010

Comment: I should mention that in my previous comment that all I added was the `isRowHeader: true` to the department field definition.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier if you use only `<table>` tag

```
 <table class='table table-dark' border='2px'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Id</th>
      <th scope='col'>Name</th>
      <th scope='col'>Department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for='(emp,index) in employee' :key='index' :employee='employee'>
      <td>{{ emp.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ emp.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ emp.department }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have used axios to retrive data  and this way i am generating dynamic table. Also you can use bootstrap table to style it accordingly.

Comment: Or use the new `<b-table-simple>` component and child helper components to structure/style your table. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#simple-tables and https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#table-helper-components. Theses automatically generate the required aria attributes and roles, as well as also provide sticky header and column support

Comment: yes, even that is possible, but you will have to install its files to use the `<b-table>` tag.